# Вордпресс произвольный список

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать в админке возможность создать произвольный список и просто вывести его в шаблоне?

Comment: Какой список (назначение/задачи)? Куда вывести? Чем не устраивает стандартные списки в записях/страницах? Исправь вопрос, чтобы была понятна задача.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример создания списка из одного моего плагина. Код создает простой список разрешенных доменов.

```
// Страница настроек
function kagg_auth_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2 id="title"><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h2>

        <form action="options.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            settings_fields( 'kagg_auth_fields' );    // скрытые защитные поля
            do_settings_sections( 'kagg_auth_page' );  // секции с настройками (опциями)
            submit_button();
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Регистрируем настройки.
 */
function kagg_auth_fields() {
    // параметры: $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback
    register_setting( 'kagg_auth_fields', 'kagg_auth_fields', 'sanitize_callback' );

    // параметры: $id, $title, $callback, $page
    add_settings_section( 'section_notice', 'Settings for woocommerce-sdm-gateway plugin', '', 'kagg_auth_page' );

    // параметры: $id, $title, $callback, $page, $section, $args
    add_settings_field( 'kagg_auth_field0', 'Allowed domains', 'fill_field0', 'kagg_auth_page', 'section_notice' );

    $val = get_option( 'kagg_auth_fields' );
    if ( empty( $val ) ) { // default values
        $val['sdm_domains'] = '';
        update_option( 'kagg_auth_fields', $val );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'kagg_auth_fields' );

// Заполняем опцию 0
function fill_field0() {
    $val = get_option( 'kagg_auth_fields' );
    $val = $val['sdm_domains'];
    ?>
    <p>List of licensed domains, one per line</p>
    <textarea name="kagg_auth_fields[sdm_domains]" rows="10" cols="50"
              class="large-text code"><?php echo esc_html( $val ); ?></textarea>
    <?php
}

// Валидация ввода
function sanitize_callback( $options ) {
    foreach ( $options as $name => & $val ) {
        if ( 'sdm_domains' === $name ) {
            $val = esc_html( $val );
        }
    }

    return $options;
}

// Добавление страницы настроек в меню
function add_plugin_page() {
    add_options_page( 'KAGG Auth', 'KAGG Auth', 'administrator', 'kagg-auth-settings', 'kagg_auth_settings_page' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_plugin_page' );
```

Так это выглядит в админке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее об API настроек можно прочитать на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html).

Использование:

```
$val             = get_option( 'kagg_auth_fields' );
$allowed_domains = explode( "\r\n", $val['sdm_domains'] );
```

В массиве $allowed_domains окажутся элементы списка.